# How to fill forms using an API having associative array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I need to use Jquery and AJAX to access an API which has this associative array-

```
{"1":"alamiz builder","2":"souroy builder","3":"vin selv builder","4":"gol mat builder","5":"sm dev builder","6":"zahi builder"}*
```

Because this array has numbers as keys, I am having a hard time displaying each value in a form element.

I have tried using `$(selector).html(data["1"])` but this is just displaying the first character of the data.

My current code is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'https://interview.switchme.in/js/2019/builder_json.php',
         success: function(data){
                 $("#b1").html(data["1"]);    
         }
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='builder_checkbox'>
        <div>Builders Filter 2</div>
        <div id="b1"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b2"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b3"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b4"><input type="checkbox" checked></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that the checkboxes display all the data from the API dynamically.
In such a way-

```
<div id="b1"><input type="checkbox">alamiz builder</div>
```

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` options. This will tell jQuery to automatically parse the response as JSON into an `Object`. Longer term, if you can change the PHP, add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before outputting the encoded JSON

Comment: Alternately, use [`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) which sets the response data-type as JSON automatically

Comment: FYI, to help with searching, there's no such thing as an "associative array" in JavaScript. There are objects, and there are arrays. What you show in the first sample is just an object with keys which happen to be parseable as numbers.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Phil Is there a way to DRY this code and use a for loop to display all the array values in their corresponding checkboxes? Also, it should be able to add additional checkboxes if required. Any inputs are appreciated (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use console.log(data) for detail about data structure.

I tried to reproduce with your JSON object, it worked.

Also need add for ajax call

```
contentType: 'application/json',
 dataType: "json",
```

Updated:

It will have issue with CORS when you use $.ajax()

Try use `$.getJSON()`, it worked

```
    $.getJSON('https://interview.switchme.in/js/2019/builder_json.php',function(data){
         //console.log(data);
         $("#b1").html(data["1"]); 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

      
 

$.getJSON('https://interview.switchme.in/js/2019/builder_json.php',function(data){
     //console.log(data);
     $("#b1").html(data["1"]); 
})
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='builder_checkbox'>
        <div>Builders Filter 2</div>
        <div id="b1"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b2"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b3"><input type="checkbox"></div>
        <div id="b4"><input type="checkbox" checked></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: GET requests do not need to set a `contentType`

Comment: If OP was going to have CORS issues, they would have had them already. There is no difference in request handling between `$.ajax()` and `$.getJSON()` so I don't know what your comment means ~ _"It will have issue with CORS when you use $.ajax()"_

Comment: sorry, i tried reproduce use $.ajax() it show that error in console :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$.ajax` is returning JSON, which is a string - you need to make the code treat it like a JavaScript object, so add `dataType: "json"` to the options object:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://interview.switchme.in/js/2019/builder_json.php',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#b1").html(data["1"]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='builder_checkbox'>
  <div>Builders Filter 2</div>
  <div id="b1"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div id="b2"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div id="b3"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div id="b4"><input type="checkbox" checked></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use `dataType: 'json'` or `$.getJSON()`. That way, if the parsing fails, it will fall through to the error / fail handler

Comment: OK @Phil, I'll add that too.

Comment: @JackBashford Thanks Jack. I was wondering whether there is a way I can use a for loop for looping all the values in the array to their corresponding checkboxes? Is that possible or do I have to repeat my code for each checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
(And don't remember, javascript codes must be above of  tag)

```html
    <div class='builder_checkbox'>
        <div>Builders Filter 2</div>
        <div id="b1"><input type="checkbox">
           <span></span> </div>
        <div id="b2"><input type="checkbox">            <span></span> 
       </div>
        <div id="b3"><input type="checkbox">            <span></span> 
       </div>
        <div id="b4"><input type="checkbox"checked>
           <span></span>
       </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'https://interview.switchme.in/js/2019/builder_json.php',
         success: function(value){
            
           var data = JSON.parse(value);
            
  
                 $("#b1 span").text(data["1"]);
              $("#b2 span").text(data["2"]);
              $("#b3 span").text(data["3"]);
              $("#b4 span").text(data["4"]);
            
         }
      });
</script>
```